# Storing a large array into a table with 10,000 columns in SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design

I want to be able to store some 100x100 matrices onto a table within my database (covariance matrices). A first good step for me would be to flatten the matrix and store the matrix structure (among other things) into a parent table.

However, creating such a table would require to make a table with about 10,000 or so columns. Writing so many field names would make my SQL code extraordinarily large, and I wouldn't know where to start if I want to query for that matrix.

Is there a neat way to specify such a table in SQL? Is there a neat way for me to set or get a particular (set of) matrix (matrices) from my database using such a table? Is there a better way?

I am using Sqlite for my databases.

Comment: so what is the table you designed, that with 10000 columns?

Comment: Each field of the table is just an entry in a matrix. Each row of this table represents a particular instance of a covariance matrix. 

Mind you, I am going this route as something like Postgresql is not available to me, and SQlite does not natively handle arrays as a field entry. I only have SQlite available.

Comment: paste in your table definition please.

Comment: [MatrixID, x1, x2, x3, x4, ..., x10000]. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

All tables with big size of same typed columns can be rotated.

For example if you have a table A like this:

```
row   col1   col2    col3 ...
1     1      2       3
2     11     12      13
```

You can simply rotate to a table with 3 colums

```
row   col   value
1     1     1
1     2     2
1     3     3
2     1     11
2     2     12
2     3     13
```

so instead of writing big sql like

```
select col1, col2, col3 ...... from A where row = 2
```

you write sql like

```
select value from A where row = 2 order by col
```

the result set was originally horizontal and now become vertical -- it is rotated and easy to handle.

Comment: This means adding a new matrix means adding a new column to my table right? Each field right of "col" will have to be a new Matrix ID. I definitely see this working although it is a bit unexpected. Mind you I have only started to play with databases quite recently.